# Chips in TextField

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How does one put a Chip in a TextField when it's selected?

I'm trying to use Chips as a way to filter Firestore data.

Each Chip will have a separate query, for example:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getName(BuildContext context) async* {
final uid = await TheProvider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("userData")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("Contacts")
    .where('searchIndex', arrayContains: searchString)
    .snapshots();
}
```

I have just created this image to better explain what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a `Chip`, use a prefix widget.